# expo emulator says warn No apps connected. Sending "reload" to all React Native apps failed but open well

Tags: react-native, expo, android-emulator, mobile-development

I am working on a `React Native` project with `Expo` for `Android`, using an Android emulator. However, when I use the `development build`, the emulator automatically opens my app. But when I try to restart it by pressing `r`, I get this message:

> warn No apps connected. Sending "reload" to all React Native apps failed. Make sure your app is running in the simulator or on a phone connected via USB.

Comment: it means the connection between expo and the simulator got lost, sometimes because of changes on network or because of timeout, just rerun the app again by pressing a for android or i for ios